# Python Slicing Newbie

Tags: python, slice

Is there a way in python to store the part I sliced and print only the part I sliced?  Meaning on the example below I sliced out "school".  I want to just print "school".  I will be trying to work on a text file later, where I will just need part of each sentence, but just trying to figure out if its doable with slicing.

```
word= "the teacher am my school"

a= word[0:-6]
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not slice it directly, then ?

```
a = word[-6:]
```

will give you `'school'`

Answer (score 4):

```
print a
```

I'm not sure what your confusion is.

**Update**: `"school"` is the part you *didn't* slice. If `"school"` is the part you're interested in, you want

```
a = word[-6:]
```

If you want both parts, slice them separately:

```
notschool, school = word[:-6], word[-6:]
```

Comment: I want to just keep the part I sliced.  Meaning "school".  Print a will print out everything but school.  I am wondering if I can just have it print "school" without slicing it from left to right.

Comment: In that case you just want `a = word[-6:]`. Essentially you want your slice to start where you want it to start, and end where you want it to end. Your initial code has it the other way around – you are starting your slice where you want to end. So if you want to generalize that, `a = word[word.find('school'):word.find('school') + len('school')]`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want just the last word in a sentence:

```
word.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation of the wording is what is causing confusion.  The slice refers to the part that is referenced (or remains), not the part that is removed.

```
'word'[0] == 'w'   # the slice is 'w' not 'ord'
```